# Weird behavior with angular when it comes to async

Tags: angular, forms, frontend

hello i'm trying to make a sign-in/signup page in the login component to verify that the user exists in the database i made a custom async validator which makes a http GET request and stores the data in a variable then i use that variable to check if the user exists or not in my promise but when i tried to do the same thing in my signup page i couldn't store the data in a variable because of Async stuff i had to use an observable to solve it
this is the login component.ts:

```
group=new FormGroup({
    email:new FormControl(null,[Validators.required,Validators.email]),
    password:new FormControl(null,[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(8)])
  },[],this.restricted.bind(this));
  UserDoesNotExist(UserData:any,UserInput:any):boolean{
    let i=0;
    let UserExistenceTest:boolean=false;
    while(i<UserData.length && !UserExistenceTest){
      if(UserInput.email==UserData[i].email && UserInput.password==UserData[i].password){
        UserExistenceTest=true;
      }else{
        i++;
      }
    }
    return UserExistenceTest;
  }
  restricted(control:AbstractControl):Promise<any>|Observable<any>{
    let UserData:any;
    let UserInput = control.value;
    this.Request.GetAllUsers().subscribe((data)=>{
      UserData=data;

    })
    let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      setTimeout(() => {
        if(!this.UserDoesNotExist(UserData,UserInput)){
          resolve({error:false})
        }else{
          resolve(null);
        }



      }, 1000)
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

this is the signup component:

```
constructor(private Request:httpRequests) {
  }
  group=new FormGroup({
    name:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    email:new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.email]),
    password:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    passwordconfirm:new FormControl('',[Validators.required],this.CheckPassword.bind(this)),
    CheckBox:new FormControl('',[Validators.requiredTrue]),
  },this.Validate.bind(this));

  CheckPassword(control:AbstractControl):Promise<any>{
        let password=this.group.value.password;
        let promise=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          if(password!='' && control.value!='' && password!=control.value){
            resolve({PassError:"invalid"});
          }else{
            resolve(null);
          }
        })
    return promise;

  }
  CheckEmail(result:any,email:string):boolean{
    if(email==''){
      return true;
    }
    let ok:boolean=true;
    result.forEach(function (element:any){
      if(element.email==email){
        ok=false;
      }
    })
    return ok;
  }
  Validate(control:AbstractControl):Promise<any>{
    let result:any;
    this.Request.GetAllUsers().subscribe((data)=>{
      result=data;
    })
    let promise=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      if(this.CheckEmail(result,control.value.email)){
        resolve({EmailError:"true"})
      }else{
        resolve(null);
      }
    })
    return promise;
  }
```

besides that in the login page the form control validators get triggered first then the form group validators do but in the signup page it doesn't work that way

Comment: It's very very hard to debug images of code.  Instead, please add a [mre] of the issue you are facing to your question